# Dynamic Table in react using material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble converting below code into reactJs, problem that i am facing this is here Table tag is used and updated based upon number of row/cell, but in react there I dont want to use createElement/appendChild,

I am using useState to get the counts, but than Table tag does not work as expected. Not sure what is way to have this Tag in react or with use of material ui.

link:https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-bird-qu9bg?file=/src/DataTable.js

```
function CreateTable() {
    var rowCtr;
    var cellCtr;
    var rowCnt;
    var cellCnt;
    var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");
    var table = document.createElement('Table');
    table.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
    table.border = '1';
    table.id = 'myTable';
    var tableBody = document.createElement('Tbody');
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
    rowCnt = document.getElementById('txtrows').value;
    cellCnt = document.getElementById('txtcols').value;
    for (var rowCtr = 0; rowCtr < rowCnt; rowCtr++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tableBody.appendChild(tr);
        for (var cellCtr = 0; cellCtr < cellCnt; cellCtr++) {
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.width = '120';
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Click me, Row:" + rowCtr + " Column:" + cellCtr));
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
    }
    myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
    }

<table contenteditable = "true">
    <tr>
        <td>Row Count</td>
        <td>Column Count</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtrows" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtcols"/></td>
        <td><button onclick="CreateTable()">Create Table</button></td>
    </tr>
</table>



<div id="myDynamicTable"></div>
```

Comment: This is way too broad of a question, for example there is no react specific code here to help out, without just providing a full solution.

Comment: ive updated the sandbox, with a basic example of how to map over an array and render the rows - https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-river-z26yn?file=/src/DataTable.js The gist of what you'll have to do is set data in state in a way that you can map over state data in the same way

Comment: @andymccullough, I dont have issue with rendering, I dont even need map function, The above sample code work as i want it, the only issue is its in pure JavaScript, and it works in react also, it is just that i am trying to use react way of creating component, there i dont want to use document.*** and **.appendChild, I am looking for alternative to these commands what can i use here, so that my function works as it working now, I dont need array of data as i will be creating array data once I save this table.

Comment: you're asking for the 'react way' of doing it, and using an array of data representing your table data, and using a `map` to render the rows is the way to do it.  You would populate the array of data using your onclick function, rather than manipulating the DOM directly.  When the state gets updated with your table data, it will rerender the component and your map function will render the table data.

Comment: @andymccullough I understand the rendering row using map function but I am not populating data in the cell, I am entering in the cell, it is is editable cell, once i go with this contenteditable = "true" will  not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the `DataTable.js` file like,

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

export default function DataTable() {
  const [rowCount, setRowCount] = useState("");
  const [colCount, setColCount] = useState("");

  const [rowCountArray, setRowCountArray] = useState([]);
  const [colCountArray, setColCountArray] = useState([]);

  const [showTable, setShowTable] = useState(false);

  const CreateTable = () => {
     rowCountArray.length = 0;
     colCountArray.length = 0;

    for (let i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
      rowCountArray.push(i);
    }
    setRowCountArray(rowCountArray);

    for (let i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) {
      colCountArray.push(i);
    }
    setColCountArray(colCountArray);

    setShowTable(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Table>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Row Count</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Col Count</TableCell>
            <TableCell></TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
              <input
                type="text"
                id="txtrows"
                value={rowCount}
                onChange={(e) => setRowCount(e.target.value)}
              />
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
              <input
                type="text"
                id="txtcols"
                value={colCount}
                onChange={(e) => setColCount(e.target.value)}
              />
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell>
              <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={CreateTable}>
                Create Table
              </Button>
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
      {showTable ? (
        <Table>
          <TableBody>
            {rowCountArray.map((row, index) => (
              <TableRow key={index}>
                {colCountArray.map((col, index) => (
                  <TableCell key={index}>
                    Row {row} - Col {col}
                  </TableCell>
                ))}
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
}
```

On click over the Create Table button, you can create a function and generate an array based on the count entered in `rowCount` and `colCount` like,

```
    const CreateTable = () => {

      rowCountArray.length = 0;
      colCountArray.length = 0;

      for (let i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
         rowCountArray.push(i);
      }
      setRowCountArray(rowCountArray);
        
      for (let i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) {
         colCountArray.push(i);
      }
      setColCountArray(colCountArray);
        
     setShowTable(true);
   };
```

Then using the following method, you can generate the table with respective rows and cols,

```
{rowCountArray.map((row, index) => (
   <TableRow key={index}>
      {colCountArray.map((col, index) => (
        <TableCell key={index}>
          Row {row} - Col {col}
        </TableCell>
       ))}
   </TableRow>
 ))}
```

[image: Edit bold-smoke-756so]

Comment: This works like charm, I guess to add the editable cell functionality i have to add input tag in the  TableCell tag

Comment: @Kartikeya, I have not used material ui So I don't know how to handle editable cell functionality but to generate the dynamic table you this should definitely help you..

Comment: Thanks, Your Ans helped to clear a lot of doubt, I had while converting this to react, now editable part looks simple to me to handle it with material ui inputText tags.